# Stream a video from androids camera to a server over RTMP

Tags: java, android, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to send a video directly from Androids camera and stream it using RTMP, I have seen two libraries one is 
http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml
and I registered but got no reply
the other one is 
http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/
which seems really outdated and not well documented

I am still newbie in androids development so I would appreciate it if someone gives me a good step by step guide on how to encode a video from the camera directly to a RTMP server where I have the server and title

Thank you

Comment: This is definitely not a "newbie" project! Recording Video is hard enough, sending MJEPG one step further. But encoding to a streaming protocol is really expert-level. At least when I last dealt with it. Which was the early 4.X Versions ...

Comment: I just looked through the developer site and it seems to be still the same. You can record in 3gpp or Mpeg4 that's it. You can with a little squeezing write to a Network socket, but you'll have to transcode the stream yourself. And from my experience, this is ugly! I guess you'll be better off sending MJPEG and encode to a streaming Format on the receiver side.

Comment: look at https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: Guys the receiver side has rtmp, I dont want to implement the encoder myself, I am asking if someone knows a ready encoder that can take the camera as a source+ the URL of the receiver and handles the job?

Comment: @AmrAbdelwahab did you manage to do RTMP encoder using android Camera??